# Getting location updates - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Dear Android Developers

I am getting the following error when I try to request location updates using the android emulator:

```
01-11 17:48:51.972: ERROR/LocationManagerService(542): requestUpdates got exception:
01-11 17:48:51.972: ERROR/LocationManagerService(542): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
01-11 17:48:51.972: ERROR/LocationManagerService(542):     at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.requestLocationUpdatesLocked(LocationManagerService.java:1000)
01-11 17:48:51.972: ERROR/LocationManagerService(542):     at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManagerService.java:968)
01-11 17:48:51.972: ERROR/LocationManagerService(542):     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub.onTransact(ILocationManager.java:96)
01-11 17:48:51.972: ERROR/LocationManagerService(542):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:287)
01-11 17:48:51.972: ERROR/LocationManagerService(542):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I am using this to get the location:

```
lastlocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

For more information: I am using Android 1.5, minSDK: 3, the emulator is gps enabled, this is my first application: a simple cell phone locator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can get a network location from the emulator using the Network provider. Try using the GPS provider and then in the DDMS perspective in Eclipse, you can 'simulate' a location update by pressing the send button (see below):

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks John for your response. I already tried it with the GPS and it works fine if the GPS is on (it is not giving me the error). The problem is that sometimes my GPS is disabled, in that case I want to get the location from the network provider.

Comment: Do you think that I will not have that error on a real android device (ie this a problem is just happening because I am using an emulator that does not support network location?)

Comment: You can have 'similar' problems on a real device as someone may have, for example, GPS switched off on their device. If you use getBestProvider, as suggested by Jay, then you should get some response. If you want accurate locations, then you could pop a message dialog, requesting the user to switch on their GPS.